# How to download from ftp without form lag vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I just made a ftp chat in vb.net and it update message from a file from a ftp server
so i add a timer with interval 1000 with this code

```
 Try
            Dim client As New Net.WebClient
            client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("fnet_1355****", "******")
            RichTextBox1.Text = client.DownloadString("ftp://185.**.***.**/htdocs/chat­.txt")
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

so .. the file is downloaded and it update the text successful but there is a problem .. every  time he download the form have a bit lag ... and i dont like that :D what i can do ?

Comment: You need to run the download operation on different thread to avoid UI thread lag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the WebClient.DownloadDataAsync() method in this context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585985/how-to-use-the-webclient-downloaddataasync-method-in-this-context)

Comment: FTP chat.  Wow.  Should have entered that in the DWTF contest.

Comment: @Arpit and... how i can do it ?

Comment: @BcComputersRO Check my Ans. It is doing same but using the async method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RichTextBox1.Text = client.DownloadString("ftp://185.**.***.**/htdocs/chat­.txt")
```

Instead of this try async method.

```
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("ftp://185.**.***.**/htdocs/chat­.txt"))
```

and then handle download string completed event.

Sample Code

```
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("ftp://185.**.***.**/htdocs/chat­.txt"));
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted); 

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     RichTextBox1.Text =e.Result;
}
```

You can also add progress indicator by handling progress change event.

Comment: i got this error on  client.DownloadStringAsync("ftp://185.**.***.**/htdocs/chat­.txt")     ---> Value of type string cannot be converted to uri ...

Comment: With a little code modification i got it Thank you , it's work perfectrly !

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do it would be to use `ThreadPool` provided by the Framework to I/O bound operation on different thread.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf DownloadFromFtp))
End Sub

Private Sub DownloadFromFtp()
    Try
        Dim client As New Net.WebClient
        client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("fnet_1355****", "******")
        Dim response As String = client.DownloadString("ftp://185.**.***.**/htdocs/chat­.txt")

        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Function() RichTextBox1.Text = response))
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Why? When WebClient has its own Async methods

Answer (score 0):

This program was the exact one I design before i learned PHP.

Here try this:

```
Dim thrd As Threading.Thread
Dim tmr As New Timer
Dim tempstring As String
Private Sub thread_start()
    thrd = New Threading.Thread(Sub() check_for_changes())
    tmr.Interval = 50
    AddHandler tmr.Tick, AddressOf Tick
    tmr.Enabled = True
    tmr.Start()
    thrd.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Not thrd.IsAlive Then
        tmr.Stop() : tmr.Enabled = False
        RichTextBox1.Text = tempstring
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub check_for_changes()
    Try
        Dim client As New Net.WebClient
        client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("fnet_1355****", "******")
        tempstring = client.DownloadString("ftp://185.**.***.**/htdocs/chat­.txt")
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Hope It Helps.

Comment: Remember, you have to use the 'thread_start' function, not 'check_for_changes' itself.