# webclient downloadata(path) working very slow

Tags: c#, webclient

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
var byt = web.DownloadData(path)
```

This code download data very slowly even application got stuck or hang.

Comment: how about the speed when download manually(from browser)?

Answer (score 0):

it's most likely a proxy issue.
try ignoring Internet Explorer proxy settings:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.Proxy = null;
var byt = web.DownloadData(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent application hanging, it is better to use asynchronous version of `DownloadData` - [`DownloadDataAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144190(v=vs.110).aspx). Example usage can be seen at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585985/how-to-use-the-webclient-downloaddataasync-method-in-this-context).

Simply - you should create a event handler for [`DownloadDataCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddatacompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event and run `DownloadDataAsync`. There is no need to use `async` or `await` modifiers.