# VB.net DownloadDataAsync to MemoryStream not working

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, webclient, memorystream

I have the following code to load a picture from the internet directly into my picturebox (from memory):

```
PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New Net.WebClient().DownloadData("LINK")))
```

The problem here is that my application freezes while the WebClient is downloading, so I thought I would use `DownloadDataAsync`

However, using this code doesnt work at all:

```
PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New Net.WebClient().DownloadDataAsync(New Uri("LINK"))))
```

It returns the error "Expression does not produce a value"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585985/how-to-use-the-webclient-downloaddataasync-method-in-this-context

Comment: [PictureBox.LoadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadasync).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, you cannot simply pass the `DownloadDataAsync` as `MemoryStream` parameter, since `DownloadDataAsync` is a Sub whereas `DownloadData` is a function returning `Bytes()`.

In order to use `DownloadDataSync`, check out sample code below:

```
Dim wc As New Net.WebClient()
AddHandler wc.DownloadDataCompleted, AddressOf DownloadDataCompleted
AddHandler wc.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf DownloadProgressChanged ' in case you want to monitor download progress

wc.DownloadDataAsync(New uri("link"))
```

Below are the event handlers:

```
Sub DownloadDataCompleted(sender As Object, e As DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs)
    '  If the request was not canceled and did not throw
    '  an exception, display the resource.
    If e.Cancelled = False AndAlso e.Error Is Nothing Then

        PictureBox1.Image =  New Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(e.Result))
    End If
End Sub

Sub DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    ' show progress using : 
    ' Percent = e.ProgressPercentage
    ' Text = $"{e.BytesReceived} of {e.TotalBytesToReceive}"
End Sub
```